# Injective order preserving homomorphism $\phi$ of two ordered abelian groups satisfies $a<b\iff \phi(a)<\phi(b)$.

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

> Exercise:
>
> Prove that every injective order preserving homomorphism $\phi$ of two ordered abelian groups satisfies $a < b \iff \phi(a) < \phi(b)$.

Definition:

A homomorphism $\phi \colon G \to H$ of ordered abelian groups is called order
preserving if $a \le b$ implies that $ \phi(a) \le \phi(b)$.

Proof of exercise:

$\implies:$ from Definition we have $a \le b \implies  \phi(a) \le \phi(b)$. Homomorphism $\phi$ is injective so we have $a < b \implies  \phi(a) < \phi(b)$ (?)

$\Longleftarrow: \phi(a) < \phi(b)$ and $\phi$ is order preserving injection. I am not sure what to do know. Should I use the fact that kernel of injective function has only one element?

Comment: If $a\lt b$, then $a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$, so $\phi(a)\leq\phi(b)$ and $\phi(a)\neq\phi(b)$, hence $\phi(a)\lt \phi(b)$. So that part is correct, but needs expansion. For the converse, well, we must either have $a\lt b$, $a=b$, or $a\gt b$. Why is only the first one possible, given your assumption and what you already proved in the forward direction?

Comment: If $ϕ(a)=ϕ(b)$ then $a=b$. Why do we need consider $ϕ(a)=ϕ(b)$, not $ϕ(a) \neq ϕ(b)$?

Comment: Huh? I don't understand the question.

Comment: In forward direction I need to consider $a<b, a=b, a>b$ or $ϕ(a)<ϕ(b), ϕ(a)=ϕ(b), ϕ(a)>ϕ(b)$ ?

Comment: $ϕ(a)<ϕ(b) \implies ϕ(a) \leq ϕ(b)$ and $ ϕ(a) \neq ϕ(b) \implies ϕ(a) \leq ϕ(b)$ and $ a \neq b$ This is moment when I'm getting lost.

Comment: Your "forward" direction (proving that if $a\lt b$ then $\phi(a)\lt\phi(b)$) is essentially correct; you just needed a bit more words: $a\lt b$ is equivalent to $a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$. So to prove that $\phi(a)\lt\phi(b)$, it is enough to show that $\phi(a)\leq\phi(b)$ and that $\phi(a)\neq\phi(b)$; you get $\phi(a)\leq\phi(b)$ from he fact that $\phi$ is order-preserving, and you get that $\phi(a)\neq\phi(b)$ from the fact that $\phi$ is one-to-one . You don't need to consider any cases.

Comment: I am suggesting that to prove the converse, "backward" direction (that if $\phi(a)\lt \phi(b)$, then $a\lt b$), you could consider cases. You **assume** that $\phi(a)\lt\phi(b)$. Now, because the group is ordered, you must have either $a\gt b$, $a=b$, or $a\lt b$. But if $a\geq b$, then since $\phi$ is order preserving, then... and therefore, the only possible option is that...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin.  Why when you use Jax in a comment it in part overlaps with the text?  Such is hard to impossible to read.  A minor example:   a >,ba =,bor.

Comment: The essence is to prove every order preserving bijection of a linear order is an order isomorphism.  Presumably the group is linearly ordered.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: No, that does not happen in any of my interfaces. That’s a problem with your reading method/viewer/device, not with MathJax or with how or what I write.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Arturo Magidin is right. I don't have any problems.

Comment: Do you assume that $\le$ is a total order or is it a partial order?

Comment: @PaulFrost: The use of "ordered abelian groups" implies a total order; otherwise, they would be "partially ordered abelian groups".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay, this explains your comment concerning the "backward" direction.